# How to define Subroutines and functions?

Tags: arcobjects, vba

I am working in VBA. My error is `sub and function are not defined`.  Here is my code:

```
Private Sub CreateMap(cboDistrict As String)   
    Dim mapDocument As New mapDocument
    If mapDocument.IsPresent("K:\TASS\4_MAPPING_DATA_SUPPORT\Traffic_Mapping\District_Maps\2012\Abilene\Abilene_Base_Map.mxd") Then
        mapDocument.Open ("K:\TASS\4_MAPPING_DATA_SUPPORT\Traffic_Mapping\District_Maps\2012\Abilene\Abilene_Base_Map.mxd")
    End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to open an mxd when the Map button is pushed.

Comment: Have you quoted the error message exactly?

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted your question, but I suspect whoever did, felt the question might be better suited for StackOverflow.  Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7715070/125400) addresses your issue.  Try putting `Call` in front of the mapDocument.Open.

Comment: are you running if from an opened Mxd? on which line do you get error? pls post more info..

Comment: Are you using "IMapDocument.Open" method? Doesn't it get two parameters? 
http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000008n1000000

Comment: is there a question here? What is the error message you get?

Answer (score 2):

I think the usage should be

```
Dim mapDocument As IMapDocument
set mapDocument = New MapDocument

 If mapDocument.IsPresent ....
```

One more thing you can try

```
Dim pDoc As IDocument
Dim pApp As IApplication
Set pDoc = New MxDocument
Set pApp = pDoc.Parent
pApp.Visible = True
pApp.OpenDocument ("K:\TASS\4_MAPPING_DATA_SUPPORT\Traffic_Mapping\District_Maps\2012\Abilene\Abilene_Base_Map.mxd"")
pApp.RefreshWindow
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to add references to make your answer more authoritative?

Answer (score 2):

It is not tested

```
string cboStations;
string cboDistrict;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication theMap = ArcMap.Application;
if (cboDistrict == "Abilene") 
   theMap.OpenDocument(@"K:\TASS\4_MAPPING_DATA_SUPPORT\Traffic_Mapping\District_Maps\2012\Abilene\Abil‌​ene_Base_Map.mxd");
```

**EDIT :**
Maybe you are getting this error because of calling a method with wrong number of parameters. Please go through [IMapDocument.Open Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0012000008n1000000)

Comment: ... you are calling mapDocument.Open() method in a wrong way. The mapDocument.Open() method takes two arguments not one.