# Setting path to Variable to be able to open new mxd?

Tags: arcobjects, mxd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to define Subroutines and functions?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46634/how-to-define-subroutines-and-functions)

I know its strange but I need to be able to open a new mxd into an existing one. Yes, it can be done. All I need to do is set a path to a variable(most likely iApplication). From dialog box, user selects a district name to open that districts mxd. I believe the code would be Application.iApplication.OPenDocument(Path to folder). But I am having trouble with the sub and function declaration. It keeps giving me an error of sub and function not declared. Sample is below : 
Private Sub cmdMap_Click()

```
Dim District As String
Dim map As mapDocument
Set map = New mapDocument

map.District = ComboBox("Abilene")

Call DrawTasks.RenderMap("Abilene")

Application.IApplication.OpenDocument ("K:TASS......")
```

End Sub

Comment: Are you using ArcCatalog?

Comment: IApplication.OpenDocument Method does not work in ArcCatalog according to: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/OpenDocument_Method/00230000003t000000/

Comment: What do you want to do once you 'open' it? Do you need to just read things from it, or cause it to Open in a new ArcMap window?

Comment: Michelle, you seem to be asking exactly the same question over and over again. Please just respond to the requests to clarify the original question.  More info about how this site works is available at our [faq].

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but isn't [IMapDocument.Open Method](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/Open_Method/0012000008n1000000/)  used toopen an ".mxd"? Maybe you can read the documentation for this method. It may help you.

**ADDITION:**

It is not tested

```
string cboStations;
string cboDistrict;

ESRI.ArcGIS.Framework.IApplication theMap = ArcMap.Application;
if (cboDistrict == "Abilene") 
   theMap.OpenDocument(@""K:\TASS\4_MAPPING_DATA_SUPPORT\Traffic_Mapping\District_Maps\2012\Abilene\Abil‌​ene_Base_Map.mxd"");
```

Comment: Devdatta!! All the reader needs to do is look at the map document no editing will be available. Correct Emi!! I am having trouble using the iApplication though. I am not understanding why my sub and function are not working!! Here's my new code.Dim cboStations As String
    Dim cboDistrict As String
    
    Dim theMap As mapDocument
    Set theMap = New mapDocument
    
    If cboDistrict = "Abilene" Then
    IApplication.OpenDocument ("K:\TASS\4_MAPPING_DATA_SUPPORT\Traffic_Mapping\District_Maps\2012\Abilene\Abilene_Base_Map.mxd")
    Elif
        End

Comment: I never worked with VB.net. So, I don't know if there is any problem with your declarations.

Comment: I have edited my answer. You can go through this.